# How to write some text as bytes (without encoding)

Tags: c#, binary

I need to generate a file that will be read by another system. For this reason, it should be in binary, not text with some encoding.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write("Some text" + Environment.NewLine);
                writer.Write("Some more text" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

When I open the file and look at it, I can see some special character at the start of each line, similar to this (hard to paste it here, since it doesn't show the same):

~Some text

~Some more text

What am I doing wrong/forgetting?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a -1 (not from me :) ) because, as @John Skeet says, there isn't such a thing as 'no encoding'. You're probably using ASCII or ISO-8859-1. You should verify what encoding you need and update the question.

Comment: Despite there is no such thing as "no encoding" does not mean this is not a good question. Actually because you must always have encoding, this is a very good question.

Comment: @GvS - My sentiments exactly.

Comment: when you need to store as a string to pass it to a method in a class that is in a jar and you don't want extra bytes for everything that is over chr 127... the op question would be "how to create a custom encoding?" then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such concept as text without an encoding. It's like wanting to save an abstract image to disk without specifying any image format. (Even "raw" is a kind of encoding for images - you need to agree on a way of communicating the width, height, byte order, colour depth somehow.)

I suggest you just fix on one encoding (e.g. `Encoding.Unicode` or `Encoding.UTF8`) and write the text that way.

As for why `BinaryWriter.Write(text)` is putting "special characters" at the start of each line, did you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx) for what it does?

> Writes a length-prefixed string to this stream in the current encoding of the BinaryWriter, and advances the current position of the stream in accordance with the encoding used and the specific characters being written to the stream.

and

> A length-prefixed string represents the string length by prefixing to the string a single byte or word that contains the length of that string. This method first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer, and then writes that many characters to the stream by using the BinaryWriter instance's current encoding.

So what you're seeing is the length-prefix... but then it will use whatever encoding you've set up for the `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: @[Jon Skeet] Thanks for your answer. I don't think I understood you. What is the difference between File.WriteAllText and File.WriteAllBytes? I want to save the text as binary. Can it not be stored as something like RAW? The problem is that I don't know how the other system is going to read my file. Am I making sense?

Comment: @HappyCoder4U: There's no equivalent of "raw" for text. Text and binary are fundamentally different. It's like asking for a "raw" form of the word that in English is "cat", without reference to any particular language. Words are defined by language, just like the binary form of text is defined by an encoding. If you don't know how the other system is going to read your file, you're completely stuck. You absolutely *have* to know that.